# What is the difference between AudioClip and Clip in java?

Tags: java, clip

In my game I'm trying to add sfx and other sound elements. I used AudioClip for everything (BGM, sfx, etc). Now I would need to check if a sfx is already in loop or not. I would like to archieve that if the character is close to the portal a sfx should be played in loop. If its out of distance it should stop. I read that there is a .isRunning() function but it can be used only with Clip as far as I see. Here is a part of my code.

So what is the difference between AudioClip and Clip?

```
if (hero.getHeroX() > (MAZECOL - 5) * 30 && hero.getHeroY() > (MAZEROW - 4) * 30)
    if (portalSFX is not in loop)
        portalSFX.loop();
else
    portalSFX.stop();
```

Comment: It looks like two different APIs; `AudioClip` is in `java.applet` while `Clip` is in `javax.sound.sampled`.

Comment: are there any pros and cons for them? as I really need that .isRunning() function should I change all of my sounds to Clip instead of AudioClip? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AudioClip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/AudioClip.html) belongs to the applet API. There is really no point in using it. It is older and presents limited functionality.

[`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) belongs to `javax.sound.sampled`. It can be obtained from [`AudioSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html) and there is an official tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to check if an AudioClip is in loop/already playing or not? But I will try to change it to Clip anyway.

Comment: *"Is there any way to check if an AudioClip is in loop/already playing or not?"* No, there is not. Switching to Clip is the right decision here.